# I need help deciphering what looks like a binary message

Tags: number-sequence, computer-puzzle, sequence, computer-science

I was watching a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/llg5SUwNmJM) and it’s filled with secret messages and codes. The last two codes were in binary and inserting them into a translator provided correct answers. However, that's not working for code #3:

[image: Screenshot of the code.]

Below is a text version:

> 1001-10100 10011 10100-1000-101 1111-1110-1100-1100110111-1-1100110100-1111 10101-1110-100-101-10010-10011-10100-1-1110-100

How can I solve this code? If someone can help point me in the right direction without fully disclosing the answer I’d be grateful!

Comment: The codes in the video are puzzles. They are designed to be solved by finding patterns. Your intuition to use a binary to ASCII converter worked, but as the codes get more difficult, you have to try harder. The numbers are still binary, but the don't represent ASCII codes. Can you see what they represent instead? You may have to look into how [binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) work or even write a small program to convert them to decimal. _It's the only way to understand._ `:)`

Comment: @MOehm that sounds like a great answer!

Comment: Thank you, guess I’m going to have to go a lot more involved in this than I originally thought haha. Time to go on a little learning journey!